# How to clear Jest mock implementation for next tests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm setting up Jest to test a typescript application.

**How do I clear a mocked function and restore the original implementation for other tests?**

To mock the function I've used: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce()

So far I've tried jest.clearAll() / resetModules() / resetAllMocks() in beforeEach as well as afterEach without any success.

## app.test.ts

```
import App from './app';
import { DbService } from './lib/dbService';

describe('App', () => {    
  let dbService: DbService;
  let app: App;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    dbService = new DbService();
    app = new App();
  });

  describe('getUsers', () => {

    it('Should get an array users #1', () => {
      expect(app).toBeInstanceOf(App);
      const allUsers = app.getAllUsers();
      expect(allUsers[0].id).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should return an error #2', () => {
      DbService.prototype.getAllUsers =         
        jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
            return new Error('No connection to DB');
         });
      expect(app.getAllUsers()).toEqual(new Error('No connection to DB'));
    });

    it('Should get an array users #3', () => {
       expect(app).toBeInstanceOf(App);
       const allUsers = app.getAllUsers();
       expect(allUsers[0].id).toBeDefined();
    }); 
  });
});
```

## app.ts

```
import { DbService } from './lib/dbService';

export default class App {
  private dbService: DbService;

  constructor() {
    this.dbService = new DbService();
  }

  getAllUsers() {
    return this.dbService.getAllUsers();
  }
}
```

## lib/dbService.ts

```
let instance: DbService;

export class DbService {
  constructor() {
    if (!instance) {
      instance = this;
    }
    return instance;
  }

  getAllUsers() {
   return [
     {id: 1, username: 'john'},
     {id: 2, username: 'bill'}
    ]
  } 
}
```

I expect test #3 to pass like test #1, but it actually fails with the following error:

```
FAIL  src/app.test.ts
  App
   getUsers
    √ Should get an array users #1 (3ms)
    √ should return an error #2 (1ms)
    × Should get an array users #3 (1ms)

● App › getUsers › Should get an array users #3

  TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

    31 |        expect(app).toBeInstanceOf(App);
    32 |        const allUsers = app.getAllUsers();
  > 33 |        expect(allUsers[0].id).toBeDefined();
       |                       ^
    34 |     });
    35 |   });
    36 | });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the `jest` way of achieving this but I think you could save the original method implementation in a variable and re-set the method after every test in case it was mocked in a test.

E.g.

```
describe('App', () => {    
  let dbService: DbService;
  let app: App;
  let originalGetAllUsersFn = DbService.prototype.getAllUsers;

  //...

  afterEach(() => {
    // restore mocked method
    DbService.prototype.getAllUsers = originalGetAllUsersFn;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jest has setup/teardown functions:

https://flaviocopes.com/jest/#setup
To do something once before all the tests run, use the beforeAll() function:

```
beforeAll(() => {
 //do something
})
```

To perform something before each test runs, use beforeEach():

```
beforeEach(() => {
 //do something
})
```

Teardown
Just as you can do with setup, you can also perform something after each test runs:

```
afterEach(() => {
 //do something
})
```

and after all tests end:

```
afterAll(() => {
 //do something
})
```

Do the mocking in the setup functions and restore in the teardown

Comment: But how do I use setup and restore for a single test?

Comment: If you want to mock only in a particular case then unfortunately you need to also restore in that test. It may be long and slow but you can mock for all and restore all before/after each test respectively (i.e. all your mocks in beforeEach()) Not the greatest solution but it's what I've had to do in the past